# Getting the return value from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a project in which I need to save the return value of a stored procedure.

```
declare @query_bereich nvarchar(500)

SET @query_bereich = 'select bereich' + convert(varchar(2), @bereich) +
                     ' from ImpArtGruppe where Artikelnummer = ' + @artnum 

set @artgrp = (EXEC sp_executesql @query_bereich)
select @artgrp = ISNULL(@artgrp, '')
select @artgrp
```

Now the problem I'm having is, that the return value is always 0. I guess this is by default because in another scenario the would be a restulset that can have more than one value. But in my case I have made sure the the query always returns only the one.

I have also tried foillowing code I found on google:

```
EXEC @artgrp = sp_executesql @query_bereich
```

But this did also not work.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no stored procedure in your example code.  It looks like you are building a dynamic T-SQL query, and want to store the result from that.

Here's one way, using `sp_executesql`, and assuming the type of `@artgrp` is `varchar(50)`:

```
declare @query_bereich nvarchar(max)
set @query_bereich = 'select @artgrp = bereich' + convert(varchar(2),@bereich) +
    ' from ImpArtGruppe where Artikelnummer = ''' + @artnum + ''''
declare @artgrp varchar(50)
exec sp_executesql @query_bereich, '@artgrp varchar(50) output', @artgrp output
```

Comment: This is it. I forgot the whole thing with the parameters and OUTPUT.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to return scalar values (that is: nothing complex), you should use sql functions instead.

See here: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186755.aspx)

A stored procedures simply returns the number of database rows, that where affected by its call. That is why in your case the procedure returns 0.

Comment: the sp_executesql Procedure is one already provided by MSSQL Server. I did not write it myself. What it does is execute a query i defned before so I can have dynamic Column names.

Comment: The answer lies here: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188001.aspx) The procedure you are calling is meant for Queries that change data (insert, update, delete) Its return value is 0 for success and something else for failure. the returned 0 means, that the select was successful, which of course does not help you. So you should look for another way to do this